# How to verify my account in order to use the Kovan testnet?

Tags: ether, testnets, kovan

I am new to parity and kovan-testnet.

I have to verify my account in order to receive keth.

I am confused as to where to execute the following code:

```
curl http://github-faucet.kovan.network/url --data "address=https://gist.github.com/[github_username]/[gist_hash]"
```

Comment: What I don't understand about the instructions is what it means to "create a gist page with your wallet address". I know how to create a gist, but where does the address go? The name of the gist? The name of a file in the gist? or what?

Answer (score 0):

So you first need to create a gist page with your wallet address, you can  do that here : https://gist.github.com/ 
that will create a page with an url similar to this https://gist.github.com/didil/903f79a59dc84d20cf7d52207416368c
afterwards you just need to execute this command in your command line tool (terminal in mac os or bash in linux or the command prompt for windows) :

```
curl http://github-faucet.kovan.network/url --data "address=https://gist.github.com/didil/903f79a59dc84d20cf7d52207416368c"
```

make sure you replace the gist address with your own

Comment: step by step procedure please for command prompt @Adil

Comment: not sure what you mean, you can't find the command prompt on your os ?

Comment: I have found command prompt, should i directlly write the code, I mean doesn't it matter whether directory is c,d or e @Adil

Comment: no it doesn't matter, you just need to have curl installed beforehand, that also depends on your os

Comment: where to run "$parity --help" @Adil